# How can you make a command shut down a discord bot? (Using Javascript, Node.js and Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

same as title. How do i create a command that will shut down my Discord Bot?

Comment: `process.exit()`

Answer (score 0):

As tehhowch suggested, you may use `process.exit()`, or, you may use the method [destroy](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=destroy) of [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

Example:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "shutdown") { // Note that this is an example and anyone can use this command.
        message.channel.send("Shutting down...").then(() => {
            client.destroy();
        })
    }
})
```